# How to change background color of active radio button in react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs

In a React project I've radio buttons enlisting calendar dates and days. My intention is to change the background color of those radio buttons and also persist it. It should not fade away when clicked on screen.

The following is the code for reference:

```
{newDate.map((data, i) => (
          <ButtonGroup toggle style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <GridListTile style={gridListStylePhoto}>
              <h5>{currday(data.getDay())}</h5>
              <ToggleButton
                key={i}
                type="radio"
                active="true"
                variant="light"
                name="radio"
                value={currday(data.getDay()) + " " + data.getDate()}
                checked={radioValue === data.getDate()}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  handleChange(e);
                }}
              >
                <br />
                {data.getDate()}
              </ToggleButton>
            </GridListTile>
          </ButtonGroup>
        ))}
```

Below is the styling reference:

```
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.btn-light {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: transparent;
}

.btn-light:checked {
  background-color: red // Here is color doesn't change
}
```

What could be done in order to change the background color of above radio buttons?

Please refer to the below Codesandbox link.

Codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hcbxl

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about clicking/selection radio. Please update it

Comment: Ok so what is the best possible solution?

Comment: 1. Please [edit] and update the question with the info you provided in comments like *"I mean when the radio button is active on selection"*
2. Your `demo.js` has a lot of boilerplate code. Please see [mcve].

when you update questions it'll get bumped in the activity feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the class for each radio button using your existing onChange event.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const newData = e.target.value;
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleButtonNew.active");
    [].forEach.call(elems, function (el) {
      el.classList.remove("active");
    });
    e.target.closest("label").classList.toggle("active");
    setRadioValue(newData);
};
```

And add your desired styles to that class

```
.active {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Its not getting changed. Can you please refer codesandbox link mentioned above

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: Wow almost done but, when clicked on others that doesn't get unselected

Comment: Very good logic, but, not completed as others are getting selected as well... Its feeling like checkbox whereas those are radio buttons

Comment: Oh, since  you said *persist it* I left it as it is.

Comment: Ya regarding persistence its perfect... but, radio buttons are to be selected only one... Right?

Comment: You are GREAT... that's enough to say... Thanks very much